Split the data into separate columns and later merge them as one column
I am new to python and need some guidance on how i can split a column where data is separated by  ";"
Example Data:
EMP_ID
1111909;ZMLed1;U937300;ZMLed2;
1281954;CMkzie;U028915;Z45134;QCPUY987;;C005528;QCP2155Q
1471999;U017735;WR01Cook;QCPUK783;

How I can separate the EMP_ID into separate columns and then merge them back as single column like
EMP_ID
1111909
ZMLed1
U937300
ZMLed2
1281954
CMkzie
U028915
Z45134
QCPUY987
C005528
QCP2155Q
1471999
U017735
WR01Cook
QCPUK783

I tried:
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT DISTINCT EMP_ID FROM TABLE", conn)


df[
    ['EMP_ID_1', 'EMP_ID_2', 'EMP_ID_3', 'EMP_ID_4', 'EMP_ID_5',
     'EMP_ID_6', 'EMP_ID_7']
] = df['EMP_ID'].str.split(';', expand=True)

also tried,
S = df.split(";")


Why do you want to split it into separate columns? If that's just a means to getting to the end result, you don't need to do that. I guess you weren't aware of .explode(), right?

BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

A one-step approach could be to extractall with a regex getting any series of characters that are not ;:
out = df['EMP_ID'].str.extractall('([^;]+)')[0]

Output:
   match
0  0         1111909
   1          ZMLed1
   2         U937300
   3          ZMLed2
1  0         1281954
   1          CMkzie
   2         U028915
   3          Z45134
   4        QCPUY987
   5         C005528
   6        QCP2155Q
2  0         1471999
   1         U017735
   2        WR01Cook
   3        QCPUK783
Name: 0, dtype: object

As DataFrame:
df['EMP_ID'].str.extractall('(?P<EMP_ID>[^;]+)').droplevel('match')

Output:
     EMP_ID
0   1111909
0    ZMLed1
0   U937300
0    ZMLed2
1   1281954
1    CMkzie
1   U028915
1    Z45134
1  QCPUY987
1   C005528
1  QCP2155Q
2   1471999
2   U017735
2  WR01Cook
2  QCPUK783

If needed, you can also join this to the original DataFrame.
Regex demo

use explode after str.split
out = df['EMP_ID'].str.split(';').explode()

out:
0     1111909
0      ZMLed1
0     U937300
0      ZMLed2
0            
1     1281954
1      CMkzie
1     U028915
1      Z45134
1    QCPUY987
1            
1     C005528
1    QCP2155Q
2     1471999
2     U017735
2    WR01Cook
2    QCPUK783
2            
Name: EMP_ID, dtype: object

generate example
import pandas as pd
data = {'EMP_ID': ['1111909;ZMLed1;U937300;ZMLed2;', 
                   '1281954;CMkzie;U028915;Z45134;QCPUY987;;C005528;QCP2155Q', 
                   '1471999;U017735;WR01Cook;QCPUK783;']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


Update
new example
import pandas as pd
data = {'colA': ['a;b;c', 'd;e'], 'colB': ['f', 'g']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df:
    colA    colB
0   a;b;c   f
1   d;e     g

edit column & explode
out = df.assign(colA=df['colA'].str.split(';')).explode('colA')

out
    colA    colB
0   a       f
0   b       f
0   c       f
1   d       g
1   e       g


getting this error: ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

@AnimeshJain This code shouldn't do that. How are you using it?

@AnimeshJain I've attached the code to generate  your example, so please run the code in the example above to see if it generates an error and comment.

basically I am pulling multiple columns from aa table like
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT DISTINCT EMP_ID, Name, sup_name, man_name FROM TABLE", conn)
and then used the code you just provided, getting the results but how can i modify it to pull rest all columns as well for each of these separate rows?

Based on your code you posted in your question I believe you need:
df_out = df["EMP_ID"].str.split(";").explode()
df_out = df_out[df_out != ""]
print(df_out.to_frame())

Prints:
     EMP_ID
0   1111909
0    ZMLed1
0   U937300
0    ZMLed2
1   1281954
1    CMkzie
1   U028915
1    Z45134
1  QCPUY987
1   C005528
1  QCP2155Q
2   1471999
2   U017735
2  WR01Cook
2  QCPUK783


EDIT: If you want to expand to columns:
df_out = df["EMP_ID"].str.split(";", expand=True)
df_out.columns = [f"EMP_ID_{c+1}" for c in df_out.columns]

print(df_out)

Prints:
  EMP_ID_1 EMP_ID_2  EMP_ID_3  EMP_ID_4  EMP_ID_5 EMP_ID_6 EMP_ID_7  EMP_ID_8
0  1111909   ZMLed1   U937300    ZMLed2               None     None      None
1  1281954   CMkzie   U028915    Z45134  QCPUY987           C005528  QCP2155Q
2  1471999  U017735  WR01Cook  QCPUK783               None     None      None

